# cannot create matrix in craftcms 4.2.3

Tags: entries, matrix, entries-field, entry-type, craft4

I just created a fresh project with craftcms 4, but am running into issues creating a matrix. Even with just one block field. It gives me the error

Cannot assign string to property craft\models\MatrixBlockType::$fieldId of type ?int

I have not had this issue before, and it isn't a big matrix as there is only one field currently as a test. I cannot create any matrix fields, but can create single field types. Does anyone have this issue with craftcms 4. I have not had this issue with craftcms 3. I am running craft via ddev. Any suggestions would be a great help.

Comment: I'm getting the same error. Craft 4.2.3, just updated.